# Navigation Drawer each menu item with different background color

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hi Hello greeting to everyone,I am new to android and i just started learning android.So i implemented navigation drawer in my app but in my navigation drawer i have added menu using menu.xml

Answer (score 0):

you can always create your custom layout instead of using menu so you can design it in your way for your navigation drawer. for example.

**Navigation View**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include layout="@layout/lay_drawer_menu" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

**lay_drawer_menu.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
     android:textcolor = "whatever you want"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Activities" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt2"
     android:textcolor = "whatever you want"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Add Detail"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

**Activity**

@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

```
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.txt1: {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

               //your code.

            }
            break;
           case R.id.txt2: {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

               //your code.

            }
            break;

        }

    }
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can go through below link to create a custom Navigation Drawer on your own.You can customize it to what ever you want.
[Custom Navigation Drawer](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: is that working fine for you? you can accept so others may be benefited

Comment: i didnt triet it because i have to make changes in coding i.e. in java code so if i done with it i will update the result